# JavaScript - Copy Method of Instance

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I want a possibility to copy all properties/methods of a class *instance*:

```
class A {
    get prop1() { return 1; }
    get prop2() { return 2; }

    doStuff() {
        return this.prop1 + this.prop2;
    }
}

class B extends A {
   get prop1() { return 5; }
}
```

```
class AWrapper {
    constructor(a) {
        // [1] Copy all methods/propertys of a
        this.doStuff = () => a.doStuff() + 42;
    }
}

const a = new A();
const b = new B();
const wA = new AWrapper(a);
const wB = new AWrapper(b);
console.log(a.prop1(), wA.prop1(), wB.prop1()); // 1, 1, 5
console.log(a.doStuff(), wA.doStuff()); // 3, 45
```

I could copy each method/property by hand, but is there a simple command for `[1]`, such that `wA` has the same signature as `a`?

Comment: You can extend that class (eg: `class AWrapper extends A { ... }`)

Comment: this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends

Comment: Well I want to only work with the instance `a`. I.e. assume `a` is just an instance of A, not A directly. I've edit the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) is a tool of choice when working with mixins or decorators:

```js
class A {
    get prop1() {
        return 1;
    }

    get prop2() {
        return 2;
    }

    doStuff() {
        return this.prop1 + this.prop2;
    }
}


class B extends A {
    get prop1() {
        return 5;
    }
}


function decorate(target) {
    let mixin = {
        doStuff() {
            return target.doStuff() + 42;
        }
    }

    return new Proxy(target, {
        get(_, prop) {
            return (prop in mixin) ? mixin[prop] : target[prop];
        }
    });
}


const a = new A();
const b = new B();

const wA = decorate(a)
const wB = decorate(b)

console.log(a.prop1, wA.prop1, wB.prop1); // 1, 1, 5
console.log(a.doStuff(), wA.doStuff()); // 3, 45
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [extends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends) keyword and call the parent's (`A`) `doStuff` with : `this.doStuff = () => super.doStuff() + 42;`

```js
class A {
  get prop1() { return 1; }
  get prop2() { return 2; }

  doStuff() {
      return this.prop1 + this.prop2;
  }
}

class AWrapper extends A {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);     
      this.doStuff = () => super.doStuff() + 42;
  }
}

const a = new A();
const w = new AWrapper(a);

console.log(a.prop1, w.prop1); // 1, 1
console.log(a.doStuff(), w.doStuff()); // 3, 45
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should do it.

```js
class A {
    get prop1() { return 1; }
    get prop2() { return 2; }

    doStuff() {
        return this.prop1 + this.prop2;
    }
}
class AWrapper extends A{
    constructor(a) {
        super(a);
        this.doStuff = () => a.doStuff() + 42;
    }
}
const a = new A();
const wA = new AWrapper(a);
const wB = new AWrapper(a);
console.log(a.prop1, wA.prop1, wB.prop1); // 1, 1, 1
console.log(a.doStuff(), wA.doStuff()); // 3, 45
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a `BWrapper` class too - other than that, `extends` and `super` are all you need:

```js
class A {
  get prop1() {
    return 1;
  }
  get prop2() {
    return 2;
  }

  doStuff() {
    return this.prop1 + this.prop2;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  get prop1() {
    return 5;
  }
}

class AWrapper extends A {
  constructor(a) {
    super();
    this.doStuff = () => a.doStuff() + 42;
  }
}

class BWrapper extends B {
  constructor(b) {
    super();
    this.doStuff = () => b.doStuff() + 42;
  }
}

const a = new A();
const b = new B();
const wA = new AWrapper(a);
const wB = new BWrapper(b);
console.log(a.prop1, wA.prop1, wB.prop1); // 1, 1, 5
console.log(a.doStuff(a), wA.doStuff(wA)); // 3, 4
```

Comment: Hm. In my code I have *many* instances of `A`. Creating a Wrapper for every one is no option. I just have the concrete instance (`a` or `b`) and want to feed it into a function (in here: `AWrapper`s constructur).